# macOS Sonoma: Activate Menubar-Only App When UI Appears

Tags: swift, appkit, nsstatusitem, nsapplication, macos-sonoma

#### Context

I have a Mac app that runs from the status bar. When an `NSStatusItem` is clicked, I display an `NSWindow` rather than the standard `NSMenu`.

#### Problem

Before Sonoma, when the `NSStatusItem` was clicked I used the `activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)` API that is now deprecated to ensure that my application became the active app. This worked perfectly, so Apple decided to nuke it.

On Sonoma, macOS now shows my window but does not activate the application, which means the user must click on the `NSStatusItem` and then click again on the window before interacting with my UI. It also produces a very jarring experience when the user *does* click in the window, because the active application finally switches, but not when the user expected it. Both my window and the previously-active app suddenly redraw in different states. It's ugly.

Worst of all, the problem occurs only about 85% of the time. 15% of the time, the system activates my app when the UI is shown. I cannot nail down a pattern for it yet, but this jives with the AppKit release notes that suggest the system "may" activate my App. (If some stupid, over-engineered, machine-learning gobbldegook thinks it's worth doing, no doubt.)

#### Question

How do I tell the system that my app *NEEDS* to become active when my NSStatusItem is clicked because (A) that's what the user expects and (B) the alternative looks like macOS is broken?

#### Attempts

I have tried setting `NSApplication.shared.setActivationPolicy()` with both `.accessory` and even `.regular` (even though that adds a Dock icon and menubar) and the problem persists.

Comment: In contrary to what you say, it is a macOS standard that a menu bar menu or window is NOT activating the utility app by default.

Comment: @soundflix - I never said that such a standard exists. On macOS <14, we could ensure activation. Now, the old way of doing that no longer works on Sonoma. But apps like ControlCenter always activate appropriately, so it can be done. I’m perfectly willing to use a private API if needed because I don’t waste time with the Mac App Store.

Comment: "what the user expects" is "macOS standard".

Comment: @soundflix - no. That means what feels most natural and expected. The user clicked on an icon to make an app active but the app only became “halfway” active. I’m really not here to argue though; if you can’t help, I’m happy to let you be right.

Comment: You may not see it, but I'm trying to help you. You have not posted any example code. Are you sure that `activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)` does not work anymore on Sonoma?

Comment: *Deprecated* means it does still work and will be removed in the future. And when you select `ignoringOtherApps` and press ⌃⌘J to get to the declaration you will see *...Use NSApp.activate instead*

Comment: @vadian - unfortunately, that’s not the case here. AppKit on Sonoma now ignores the “ignoringOtherApps” parameter and calling even -activate() is no longer guaranteed to actually activate the app. All spelled out in the AppKit Release Notes. Hence…this question.

Comment: `activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)` is still work on my Mac(14.0). But I am still eager to know if there is a non-deprecated method to achieve this.

Comment: Were you able to find any solutions or workarounds for this? I have two apps with MenuBarExtras, one of which I'm fighting this problem on. The other uses a PopoverViewController for the UI hanging off the extra, and while that doesn't solve the activation issue, it does guarantee the UI is always on top of everything else.

Comment: @JoshMichaels - Unfortunately, no. I haven't found a workaround yet. Emitting a click event on an invisible button will get the job done, but that requires the app to have Accessibility permissions, which comes with the scary "This app wants to control your Mac" alert.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue where  `NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)` doesn't consistently work, but it seems that `NSRunningApplication.current.activate(options: .activateIgnoringOtherApps)` does